# Error in installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Optiplex 745

Tags: boot, system-installation, dell

I have just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04. I have created a bootable USB using rufus as per instructions. When I try booting and installing in my desktop, here is the message I get

```
SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 2014-10-06 Copyright (C) 1994-20-14 H. Peter Anvin et al 

Failed to load Idlinux.c32: 
Boot failed: please change disks and press a key to continue.
```

Comment: Your machine is *old* and the BIOS may not support the boot loader. You may want to try the 32-bit edition of Ubuntu or, purely for boot loader testing, an older, unsupported Ubuntu release like 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Your downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 may be corrupted.

Did you check the hash of your ISO? Here's a list of them (MD5SUM):

```
0d9fe8e1ea408a5895cbbe3431989295 *ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
75a7782576b1cf6fde2aa242df9e4c05 *ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-i386.iso
10fcd20619dce11fe094e960c85ba4a9 *ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.img
10fcd20619dce11fe094e960c85ba4a9 *ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso
8428cead4ee139873da19248590e354f *ubuntu-16.04.3-server-i386.img
8428cead4ee139873da19248590e354f *ubuntu-16.04.3-server-i386.iso
```

If your MD5SUM is incorrect, redownload your Ubuntu ISO.

And of course, you can redownload the ISO without checking the hash sum, recreate your live USB and boot the live USB again to see if the problem persists.